# Can I obtain unique users data from google analytics using PHP

Tags: php, google-analytics

I need do a custom report inside my web using my data in analytics with PHP, can I?

Comment: Welcome back to SO! :) Please have a read here to create a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help people answer your question, and review the following [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Good luck.

Comment: Welcome to SO? This guy is member for 4 years, 7 months @garfbradaz :)

Comment: @B001ᛦ Good spot. I copied the wrong one from my Notepad list :)

Comment: you guys really demotivate the people to ask, my bad for assuming that you can help me

Comment: I really really don't know how start to do this and that is why I can't provide more info, I need guide, please help me

Answer (score -1):

To get you started, you can check out the GA Reporting API PHP quick start: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/web-php

Another quicker option might be using [embeded Google Data Studio reports](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7450249?hl=en), of course, this means it won't be PHP based, more vanialla HTML.